How can I resolve a KeyError: 'num_parallel_tree' error?
I ran this code for a data science project on jupyterlab. it worked initially but I had some issues with my jupyterlab as it become too slow, so I had to uninstall.
I was trying to build a pipeline for preprocessing and for regression. my aim is to test using cross_val_score which of the model was best for my data
now I get an error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[22], line 18
     10 pipeline_dict={0:'LinearRegression',
     11               1: 'Lasso',
     12               2:  'DecisionTree',
     13               3: 'RandomForest',
     14               4: 'KNeighbors',
     15               5: 'XGBRegressor'}
     17 for pipe in pipelines:
---> 18     pipe.fit(x_train,y_train)

File \\?\C:\Users\FUJISU\AppData\Roaming\jupyterlab-desktop\jlab_server\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:1474, in _fit_context.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
   1467     estimator._validate_params()
   1469 with config_context(
   1470     skip_parameter_validation=(
   1471         prefer_skip_nested_validation or global_skip_validation
   1472     )
   1473 ):
-> 1474     return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)

File \\?\C:\Users\FUJISU\AppData\Roaming\jupyterlab-desktop\jlab_server\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py:475, in Pipeline.fit(self, X, y, **params)
    473     if self._final_estimator != "passthrough":
    474         last_step_params = routed_params[self.steps[-1][0]]
--> 475         self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **last_step_params["fit"])
    477 return self

File \\?\C:\Users\FUJISU\AppData\Roaming\jupyterlab-desktop\jlab_server\Lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py:433, in _deprecate_positional_args.<locals>.inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
    431 for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args):
    432     kwargs[k] = arg
--> 433 return f(**kwargs)

File \\?\C:\Users\FUJISU\AppData\Roaming\jupyterlab-desktop\jlab_server\Lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py:736, in XGBModel.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, base_margin, eval_set, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, xgb_model, sample_weight_eval_set, base_margin_eval_set, feature_weights, callbacks)
    733     obj = None
    735 model, feval, params = self._configure_fit(xgb_model, eval_metric, params)
--> 736 self._Booster = train(
    737     params,
    738     train_dmatrix,
    739     self.get_num_boosting_rounds(),
    740     evals=evals,
    741     early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds,
    742     evals_result=evals_result,
    743     obj=obj,
    744     feval=feval,
    745     verbose_eval=verbose,
    746     xgb_model=model,
    747     callbacks=callbacks,
    748 )
    750 self._set_evaluation_result(evals_result)
    751 return self

File \\?\C:\Users\FUJISU\AppData\Roaming\jupyterlab-desktop\jlab_server\Lib\site-packages\xgboost\training.py:189, in train(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, evals, obj, feval, maximize, early_stopping_rounds, evals_result, verbose_eval, xgb_model, callbacks)
    113 def train(params, dtrain, num_boost_round=10, evals=(), obj=None, feval=None,
    114           maximize=None, early_stopping_rounds=None, evals_result=None,
    115           verbose_eval=True, xgb_model=None, callbacks=None):
    116     # pylint: disable=too-many-statements,too-many-branches, attribute-defined-outside-init
    117     """Train a booster with given parameters.
    118 
    119     Parameters
   (...)
    187     Booster : a trained booster model
    188     """
--> 189     bst = _train_internal(params, dtrain,
    190                           num_boost_round=num_boost_round,
    191                           evals=evals,
    192                           obj=obj, feval=feval,
    193                           xgb_model=xgb_model, callbacks=callbacks,
    194                           verbose_eval=verbose_eval,
    195                           evals_result=evals_result,
    196                           maximize=maximize,
    197                           early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds)
    198     return bst

File \\?\C:\Users\FUJISU\AppData\Roaming\jupyterlab-desktop\jlab_server\Lib\site-packages\xgboost\training.py:93, in _train_internal(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, evals, obj, feval, xgb_model, callbacks, evals_result, maximize, verbose_eval, early_stopping_rounds)
     88     evals_result.update(callbacks.history)
     90 # These should be moved into callback functions `after_training`, but until old
     91 # callbacks are removed, the train function is the only place for setting the
     92 # attributes.
---> 93 num_parallel_tree, _ = _get_booster_layer_trees(bst)
     94 if bst.attr('best_score') is not None:
     95     bst.best_score = float(bst.attr('best_score'))

File \\?\C:\Users\FUJISU\AppData\Roaming\jupyterlab-desktop\jlab_server\Lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py:1152, in _get_booster_layer_trees(model)
   1145     num_parallel_tree = int(
   1146         config["learner"]["gradient_booster"]["gbtree"]["gbtree_train_param"][
   1147             "num_parallel_tree"
   1148         ]
   1149     )
   1150 elif booster == "gbtree":
   1151     num_parallel_tree = int(
-> 1152         config["learner"]["gradient_booster"]["gbtree_train_param"][
   1153             "num_parallel_tree"
   1154         ]
   1155     )
   1156 else:
   1157     raise ValueError(f"Unknown booster: {booster}")

KeyError: 'num_parallel_tree'

this was the code:
pipeline_lr  =Pipeline([('scaler1',StandardScaler()),('lr',LinearRegression())])
pipeline_lasso =Pipeline([('scaler2',StandardScaler()),('lasso',Lasso())])
pipeline_DTR =Pipeline([('scaler3',StandardScaler()),('DTR',DecisionTreeRegressor())])
pipeline_RFR =Pipeline([('scaler4',StandardScaler()),('RFR',RandomForestRegressor())])
pipeline_KNR =Pipeline([('scaler5',StandardScaler()),('KNR',KNeighborsRegressor())])
pipeline_XGB =Pipeline([('scaler6',StandardScaler()),('XGB',XGBRegressor())])

pipelines = [pipeline_lr,pipeline_lasso,pipeline_DTR,pipeline_RFR,pipeline_KNR,pipeline_XGB]

pipeline_dict={0:'LinearRegression',
              1: 'Lasso',
              2:  'DecisionTree',
              3: 'RandomForest',
              4: 'KNeighbors',
              5: 'XGBRegressor'}

for pipe in pipelines:
    pipe.fit(x_train,y_train)

